# Triggered send execution

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

I configured a triggered send in salesforce in order to send email using marketing cloud. However the system doesn't inject contact in the triggered email. We noticed that every record created a triggered send executions, but not individual email results.
Could you tell me when salesforce creates these records?

Answer (score 1):

Are other sends from Sales Cloud creating IER? If not, there may be a configuration issue.

If all other connection tests are indicating config is complete, see this Known Issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ep4SQAQ 
June Marketing Cloud Release - More fix work was implemented to help support the underlying infrastructure, but more work is planned for the coming releases.

Comment: Your link took me in a circle! Would you mind re-sharing?